# Securing AngularJS SPA with Spring Security 3.2

Tags: angularjs, spring-security

Any help, advice and experience is welcome.

Im currently having a separate AngularJS SPA on a Apache HTTP Server and a Spring Backend on a Tomcat 7 Servlet. The backend serves as a Rest API for the SPA.
Some rest resources will require a user to have a certain role.

I've been searching the internet for days on what and how to implement the best security strategy:

- Basic Auth
- Digest
- oAuth
- Stateless, Cookies? Sessions? Tokens? CSRF?

How would you go about communicating Spring Security in Json or XML to your SPA to show the user an authentication page or an "your successfully authenticated page"?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I finally figured out how to make the SPA authenticate with my Rest Backend.

In spring security I created a

- Custom SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler which returns a HTTP-Unauthorizated if a login attempt fails.
- Custom SavedrequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler which returns Http-Oke if a login attempt is successful.
- Custom AuthenticationEntryPoint which returns Http-Unauthorizated instead of a redirect.
- Custom LogoutSuccessHandler which returns Http-OK.
- I disabled CSRF.

If anyone needs more help feel free to let me know or message me.

Comment: Why did you decide to disable CSRF?

Comment: The reason was because I did not know how to handle the tokens in the front end with angularjs...

Comment: Ahh ok, fair enough. I did some digging around for what to do on a SPA for CSRF which led me to https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-2460. From this ticket, Rob mentions a SO at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862299/with-spring-security-3-2-0-release-how-can-i-get-the-csrf-token-in-a-page-that/20960352 which leads to a blog (http://patrickgrimard.com/2014/01/03/spring-security-csrf-protection-in-a-backbone-single-page-app/) with a pretty decent solution. The gist is a HEAD request, read the CSRF token and set an Angular HTTP interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

I highly recommend watching this [Spring's introductory video](http://spring.io/blog/2014/05/12/springone2gx-2013-replay-getting-started-with-spring-security-3-2?mkt_tok=3RkMMJWWfF9wsRokuKrAZKXonjHpfsX56eUqUKK0h4kz2EFye%2BLIHETpodcMT8NkMK%2BTFAwTG5toziV8R7bHKc1pz98QWxHr). It explains usage of Spring Security from ground up using Java configuration. Apart basic configuration, authentication and CLRF token usage also dive into field security. Uses templating on server with Thymeleaf though, but can provide a lot of wisdom for REST based app also.

Comment: I did watch it, and I do understand the concepts but the difference is I don't use templates. The only way the SPA communicates with the backend is through JSON. I could just use HTTPS Basic stateless but my site would be vulnerable to CSRF. How would I close that hole?