# How to use Spring Security with Mustache?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, mustache

I'm following the Spring Security reference, and I've got redirection to a custom login page working as described in [section 3.3](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jc-form). However, I'm not sure how to get the CSRF token in Mustache (all the examples use JSP). I've tried a few naïve things like this...

```
{{#_csrf}}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{parameterName}}" value="{{token}}"/>
{{/_csrf}}
```

...and this...

```
{{#CsrfToken}}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{parameterName}}" value="{{token}}"/>
{{/CsrfToken}}
```

...but they don't work (and I didn't really expect them to). How can I get the CSRF token in Mustache?

I'm also wondering: Where could I set a breakpoint in my code to see what Spring Security is sending as the model to my custom login view?)

Comment: Spring Security doesn't send the model; that's the Spring MVC `DispatcherServlet`. If you're going to use a template engine such as Mustache that doesn't have out-of-the-box integration, you'll need to look up the CSRF token in your controller and add it to the model yourself.

Comment: @chrylis - You were right on; thanks for your help. I added an `HttpServletRequest` argument to my `@RequestMapping` handler method and got an instance of `CsrfToken` from the "_csrf" attribute. If you add an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Like this: CsrfToken token = (CsrfToken) httpServletRequest.getAttribute("_csrf");
        model.addAttribute("token", token.getToken());

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20862299/with-spring-security-3-2-0-release-how-can-i-get-the-csrf-token-in-a-page-that

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your`application.properties`:

```
spring.mustache.expose-request-attributes=true
```

Then you have access to the `_csrf` request attribute in your template.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your application.properties:

```
spring.mustache.servlet.expose-request-attributes=true
```

Then you have access to the `_csrf` request attribute in your template.

Property was renamed from `spring.mustache.expose-request-attributes` in Spring Boot version 2.7.0.

Issue: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/28858

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure from which version this is available, but you can just add a parameter for `CsrfToken` on your controller method to get the token to be passed into the model, like so:

```
@GetMapping("/dashboard")
public String dashboard(CsrfToken csrfToken, Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("_csrf", csrfToken);
    // render page
}
```

You don't have to use `HttpServletRequest`. Now you can use your first template.

---

If the above is too tedious to do for each controller methods, we can register an interceptor instead.

Interceptor:

```
public class CsrfTokenInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                           Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {
        CsrfToken csrfToken = (CsrfToken) request.getAttribute("_csrf");
        if (modelAndView != null) {
            modelAndView.addObject("_csrf", csrfToken);
        }
    }
}
```

Bean:

```
@Configuration
public class Config {
    @Bean
    public CsrfTokenInterceptor csrfTokenInterceptor() {
        return new CsrfTokenInterceptor();
    }
}
```

Add interceptor in WebMvcConfigurer:

```
@Configuration
public class WebMvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Autowired
    CsrfTokenInterceptor csrfTokenInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(csrfTokenInterceptor);
    }
}
```