# In Spring Boot, how to use Spring EL with mustaches templates

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot, mustache

I'm using Spring Boot with Mustache templates. The "securing web" guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/securing-web/ uses thymeleaf for templating. Because of this the template can use Spring EL expressions like:

```
<div th:if="${param.error}">
  Invalid username and password.
</div>
```

How do I use Spring EL with Mustache templates? The nex snippet doesn't work:

```
{{${param.error}}}
```

And the official [sample](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-web-mustache/src/main/resources/templates) have no examples either.

Comment: Did you try `{{param.error}}` ?

Comment: @jchampemont Yes, and didn't work either.

Comment: I've give up trying to use EL and instead use this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26397168/how-to-use-spring-security-with-mustache